# Error consuming a simple remote SOAP webservice from ASPX page

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a simple webservice running on a remote server that just takes a couple of strings and integers and updates a SQL Server database. I want to use it from a new ASP.NET web form.

So today I added the remote webservice to a project by adding an App_Webservice. I added the remote wsdl filename to the .NET project (in VS2005), and named the reference **wsStoreData**.  It created a folder called wsStoreData.

The webservice has a function called **StoreRecentPage**. Here is the simple page code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;



public partial class Training_FinalPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       wsStoreData.StoreRecentPage("1", "11", 18, 100);
    }
}
```

The build fails with *"The type or namespace name 'StoreRecentPage' does not exist in the namespace 'wsStoreData' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"*

I haven't coded in .NET for a few years, so I may be missing something obvious to you. But I have looked at online examples and they don't seem to do anything different than I have done here.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: It looks like your proxy class isnt quite right, try rebuilding your proxy; this is the class that is auto generated by visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       //Idon't know name of your proxy, but it's your generated class from your Wsdl after
       //adding reference
       var proxy = new ProxyWebService();//Replace with your proxy class
       proxy.StoreRecentPage("1", "11", 18, 100);
}
```

Comment: `ProxyWebService wsStoreData = new ProxyWebService();
        wsStoreData.StoreRecentPage("1", "11", 18, 100);` now gets a similar error that ProxyWebService does not exist in the current context.